# How to split a value by str_replace into wpallimport for using category

Tags: php, str-replace, wpallimport

For importing articles by `wpallimport`, I want them to be in the right category. In the csv file there is a column with several (sub) categories, separated by a space. Now i want to replace the space with `>` by means of the `str_replace` function, only there are article groups with the text "abcd & efgh", the space and `&` space will also have to be replaced by `>` sign. Is this possible?

The value `groep[1]` is: `PRINTER INKT & PAPIER`

`[str_replace(" ", ">", {groep[1]})]`

It gives as result:

```
printer (group)
--inkt  (subgroup)
---&    (subgroup)
----papier (subgroup)
```

i need as result:

```
printer (group)
-inkt & papier (subgroup)
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should tag your question with the language(s) relevant to what you're working on - better chance of the right expert finding you quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression functions, instead of plain `str_replace`.

function [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)`($pattern, $string, $matches)` will find all occurrences of the pattern in the string, and return them in the first element of the output `$matches` array

```
  $s = "PRINTER INKT & PAPIER ONE & TWO & THREE";
  if (preg_match_all('#\S+(\s&\s\S+)*#', $s, $matches)) {
    // $matches[0] - is an array, which contains all parts
    print_r($matches[0]);
    // to assemble them back into a string, using another delimiter, use implode:
    $newstr = implode('>', $matches[0]);
    print($newstr); // PRINTER>INKT & PAPIER>ONE & TWO & THREE
  }
```

**UPD.** 
If you insist on using `str_replace` only, then you can apply it two times: the first - to replace all spaces to `>`, then the second - to replace `>&>` back to `&`:

```
  $s = "PRINTER INKT & PAPIER ONE & TWO & THREE";

  $newstr = str_replace('>&>', ' & ', str_replace(' ', '>', $s));
  print ($newstr); // PRINTER>INKT & PAPIER>ONE & TWO & THREE
```